# changing default prestashop seo template

Tags: seo, default, product, prestashop

Is there any way to change the default structure of SEO phrases (meta description, title, keywords, etc.) after the product is created? Seo phrases can be manually changed for each product - but how to change the generic product seo string?

I'm using presta 1.5. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by change default phrases, but if you like to change seo phrases for home page (which is used as default) you need to go Preferences>Seo & Urls and change it there.

If you need to customize how they're rendered by default for some reason, you need to override classes/Meta.php (in 1.4 it would be classes/Tools.php) and there you can find methods getMetaTags(), getProductMetas(), getHomeMetas(), completeMetaTags() etc.

Comment: Yep, that's it (completeMetaTags). Thanks a lot, dude!